# Maelstrom Pulse, targeting a face-down creature. Does it destroy other face-down creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

The big issue that needs to be addressed is that face-down creatures don't actually have a name.

So while [Maelstrom Pulse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaelstrom%20Pulse%5d) would normally remove most creature tokens just fine, its effect on face-down creatures is a bit ambiguous.

What's the rule on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Gatherer ruling on Maelstrom Pulse addresses this:

> A face-down creature has no name, so it doesn’t have the same name as anything else.

So, if you target a face-down creature with Maelstrom Pulse, nothing else will be destroyed.